# Magento add filter for date

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there anyway that we can add between . say i need to retrieve the record to see if today falls in between the start date and end date

SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sample_table` AS `main_table` WHERE (`status` = '1') AND '2016-09-27 20:25:14' BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for that

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('YourModel/ModelClass')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('start_date', array('gteq' =>$first));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('end_date', array('lteq' => $last));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
            $yourObjectReference->addFieldtofilter('start_date', array(
                array('to' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->date()),
                array('start_date', 'null'=>'')
            ))
            ->addFieldtofilter('end_date', array(
                array('gteq' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->date()),
                array('end_date', 'null'=>'')
            ));
```